# What layout should I use for my JPanels to look like this?

Tags: java, swing, layout, jpanel, layout-manager

I would like to layout some `JPanel` containers to look something like this:

[image]

However, I am not quite sure what layout would be the best to choose, since I am still new to using the layout manager and do not want to only ever use `null` as layout manager.

So I thought that I could maybe split this into two panels. One for the left side and one for the right panels. My frame is 600x600px big and has the `BorderLayout`, so I thought I maybe can do something like this, which did not work:

```
JPanel right = new JPanel();
right.setLayout(new Border Layout());
right.setSize(400, 600);

JPanel green = new JPanel();
green.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200,200));
green.setBackground(Color.green);
right.add(green, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);

//for orange same code but with center and for pink the same but with page_end

frame.add(left, BorderLayout.LINE_START);
frame.add(right, BorderLayout.LINE_END);
...
```

Comment: The `JFrame` would have a `BorderLayout`.  Create a combination `JPanel` with a `BorderLayout` and put the green `JPanel` in NORTH, the gold `JPanel` in CENTER, and the purple `JPanel` in SOUTH.  Place the combination `JPanel` in the CENTER of the `JFrame` and the gray `JPanel` in the WEST of the `JFrame`.

Comment: A lot of my answer would depend on what is supposed to happen if the GUI is made bigger? How is extra width and height assigned to the different panels?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a gridbag layout where you can have components take up multiple cells. You can find more information using this java doc: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/GridBagLayout.html

Comment: See also: [How to use GridBagLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) for more information and working examples.